# How do I get Spring to use an application.yml file in a Docker container?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I am creating a simple Java/Gradle/Spring application. I am working on Dockerizing the app. When I run the app locally without docker, it properly uses the values in my `application.yml` file. However, when I run the Docker image, it doesn't use any of the values from the `application.yml` file.

In my Dockerfile below, you'll see that I copy the `application.yml` file to the same directory as my jar in the docker image. Additionally, in the entrypoint, I reference the `application.yml` file appropriately (when I change this file path to something that is incorrect, the app breaks on start-up).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir -p /app/
ADD build/libs/image-name-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/image-name.jar
ADD build/resources/main/application.yml /app/application.yml
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app/image-name.jar --spring.config.location=file:/app/application.yml"]
```

Below is my `docker-compose.yml` file. I don't think this matters much as I got the same result by just using the `docker run ...` command, but I'd like to add it for context:

```
version: '2'

services:
  image-name:
    image: 'image-name:latest'
    container_name: image-name
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/compose-postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=admin
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  postgres_db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: postgres_db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin # TODO: CHANGE THIS LATER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password # TODO: CHANGE THIS LATER
```

I have added the Spring Actuator dependency and exposed the health endpoint using the `application.yml`. However, when I run this via the Docker image, the log below is missing (but is present when I run locally without Docker). I also get a 404 when I hit the `/actuator/health` endpoint:

```
2022-12-26T15:07:08.439-06:00  INFO 23289 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
```

Any idea as to what I am doing incorrectly? I have looked at seemingly every other related Stack Overflow thread with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Options should come first.

```
java [options] -jar jarfile [args ...]
```

In your case should be:

```
java -Dspring.config.location=/app/application.yml -jar /app/image-name.jar
```

[Reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#synopsis)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to solve this, and I really hope this helps someone in the future as well because I was banging my head against the wall over this for days. I made the change that Elyorbek Ibrokhimov had mentioned, with no luck. I even re-wrote everything in its most basic form so that it was essentially verbatim from the docs with no luck.

I then decided to simply change my configuration to change my yaml file to a sub-environment yaml file by renaming it to `application-local.yaml` and then setting the active profile to `local` and it worked. I think I will have to dive into the docs on how application.yaml files are processed after learning this. I will update this with any findings I make. Perhaps someone who understands why this happens can add their own answer.

Below is my final Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir -p /app/
ADD build/libs/image-name-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/image-name.jar
ADD build/resources/main/application-local.yml /app/application-local.yml
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.config.location=file:/app/application-local.yml -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar /app/image-name.jar"]
```

I will not mark this as the accepted answer until I fully understand why this works the way it does.

Comment: If you would use -Dspring.config.location as JVM args and not app args (before `-jar` switch in the first example it would work right away.

Comment: As I noted in this answer, Elyorbek Ibrokhimov suggested the same thing. I tried it, but it didn’t work. Once I made the changes I outlined in this answer. It worked. It is unrelated to the arguments.

Comment: I think that you did it wrong. This "answer" clearly shows that this is the case. Moreover, depending on the actual content of your yaml, it would work without active local profile as you literally pointing out which file should be used. It could be named qwerty.yml  as well and it would still work. Profile would be needed in case if yml itself specifies that it is a profile configuration (on-profile prop or something like that) or you would use `additional-location` property to specify **directory**in which Spring should try to look for application.yml as well as application-profile.yml files

Comment: It would also work out of the box if yml would be placed next to the jar file or in `config` directory. It is all stated in the docs. Bare in mind that order of resolution was changed between versions of spring thus you must use docs for the version that matches exactly spring you are using https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config

Comment: Having your example, removing either location or profile (not both) would still work as yml is next to jar so it will be picked up (but  requires `local` profile), or removing profile as you pinpointing the actual file to be used. Renaming back to application.yml and leaving it in the same place and remiving both props wil STILL work as it is default name and its location is next to jar (falls into category of "Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants)."